# How to execute post-receive git hook on All-Users repo

Tags: gerrit

I have added the post-receive hook onto the server, and when I manually push to the repo it works as expected. I am looking to execute a post-receive hook when a user signs up and refs/meta/external-ids is updated. I have confirmed that this hook is not executed when a user signs up, similarly it is not execute when a user is added through REST endpoint. I'm not sure if the gerrit hooks plugin will accomplish this task either

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "signs up" (I assume this is some Gerrit thing?), but note that Gerrit pseudo-refs are not Git refs and hence there's no actual update and hence there's no reason to expect a post-receive hook to run. You're going to need something Gerrit-specific here so there's no point in using the [tag:git] tag.

Comment: correct, a user doesn't exist in gerrit until the log in for the first time. Then their username is added to the All-Users repo which is a git NoteDB repo which stores use info. Pushing to this repo manually does execute the psot-receive hook, just however gerrit does it does not.